# How do I insert a tie (~, non-breaking space, tilde) under expl3 syntax?

Tags: spacing, expl3, syntax

I need to define a token list of the form

```
\tl_new:N  \g_silly_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_silly_tl { Text ~ and ~ a ~ tie:?? }
```

How do I do this?

---

More generally, is there a reference where one can see how to input characters 'normally' under expl3 syntax?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This question has two distinct parts, one of which is easier than the other!

The specific issue here is (presumably) not inserting a tilde but rather inserting a non-breaking space in some 'fixed' text stores as within a LaTeX3 `tl` variable. While a tilde is a convenient shortcut for this at the document level, here I think I would simply use the macro `\nobreakspace`.

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_silly_tl { Text ~ and ~ a \nobreakspace tie:?? }
```

(Note that at present there is no `expl3` code-level 'non-breaking space' function.)

On the wider issue of 'inserting non-standard catcode characters', the expandable function `\char_generate:nn` is available to create tokens of (almost) all reasonable category codes

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_silly_tl
  {
    \char_generate:nn { `\a } { 4 }
  }
```

There are a few cases that are not covered by this approach. For example, with older `expl3` releases we couldn't do active characters and you'd need to use the regex engine:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
\regex_replace_all:nnN { } { \cA\~ } \l_tmpa_tl
```

More recent versions of `expl3` can do this using `\char_generate:nn`, so it's more of a historical note.

The second option is stick to the 'traditional' `\lowercase` trick, using `expl3` naming of course

```
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:n { `\@ }
\char_set_lccode:nn { `\@ } { `\~ }
\tex_lowercase:D
   {
     \group_end:
     \tl_set:Nn \l_silly_tl { Text ~ and ~ a @ tie:?? }
   }
```

(Notice that there is no public interface to `\lowercase` beyond the saved-primitive.)

Comment: Is there any update about "(Note that at present there is no `expl3` code-level 'non-breaking space' function.)"?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé That's still true, though you could now ``\char_generate:nn { `\~ } { 13 }``

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry to ask again: any change in the answer to Denis's question in the 2 1/2 years or so since?

Comment: @Noldorin Why would you need anyway? An active `~` (`~` in normal catcode regime) is by default exactly equivalent to `\nobreakspace{}` which can be used without any issue in expl3 code. (actually, it expands to that)

Comment: @user202729 For a parsing macro.

Comment: @Noldorin Ah, I only understand what that mean re-reading that comment now ("parsing" means "parse a user-provided token list"). In that case even if expl3 provides some interface to typeset a non-breaking space (e.g. `\nobreakspace:`) it would be useless for that purpose, so stick with regex or \lowercase. (my answer below might also be interesting)

Comment: @Noldorin If Unicode fonts are being used, slot 160 is NBSP (no-break space), so the user could do `\tl_new:N \c_nbspace_tl
\tl_set:Nn \c_nbspace_tl { \tex_Uchar:D 160 }` and then `a \c_nbspace_tl tie`; or enter the character directly or with a macro, or `\Uchar160`, etc, or indirectly via a `\use:c{}` etc, so the parsing might need to use x-expansion.

Comment: @user202729 Yes, that's what I meant; I should have been more explicit. What do you mean by "useless for that purpose", however?

Comment: @Cicada That's good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recently made a package to do this. (now on CTAN.)

(remark: clearly everything the package can do `l3regex` and `lowercase` can also do, but this package provides a more convenient syntax...)

With the package, you can write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{precattl}    % ← this package!
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\precattl_exec:n {
    \tl_new:N  \g_silly_tl
    \tl_set:Nn \g_silly_tl { Text ~ and ~ a \cA\~ tie:?? }
    % ↑ l3regex-replacement-like syntax, but not exactly identical.
    % Note that you can embed it directly into the code itself
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark, I think you need a sufficiently new expl3 version, otherwise the nested tl-analysis map bug will make the result incorrect. (or include my tlanalysispatch.sty for a temporary patch to the kernel until you update it.)