# The \lowercase trick

Tags: tex-core

We have a number of questions or rather answers using (and explaining) the `\lowercase` “trick”.

```
\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\.
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1{foo with #1}
```

However, after reading on uppercase and lowercase codes I started wondering how it is possible that it is working. Quoting *TeX by Topic*:

> To each of the character codes correspond an uppercase code and a
>   lowercase code [...]. These can be assigned by
>
> ```
> \uccode number equals number
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> \lccode number equals number .
> ```
>
> In IniTeX codes `` `a ``..`` `z ``, `` `A ``..`` `Z `` have uppercase code
>   `` `A ``..`` `Z `` and lowercase code `` `a ``..`` `z ``. All other
>   character codes have both uppercase and lowercase code zero.
>
> The commands `\uppercase{...}` and `\lowercase{...}` go through their argument
>   lists, replacing all character codes of explicit character tokens by their uppercase and lowercase code respectively if these are non-zero, without changing the category codes.

The last sentence made me thinking: how can the “trick” work if both `~` and the symbol that gets a definition have lowercase code=0? My naive expectation would be that

```
\lccode`\~=`\.
```

gives `~` the same lowercase code it had before and is equivalent to `` \lccode`~=0 ``. But to me this would imply that the “trick” shouldn't work? How come it *does* work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\verb+\the\lccode`. += \the\lccode`. \par
\verb+\the\lccode`~ += \the\lccode`~

\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\.
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1{foo with #1}

\catcode`\.=13

.{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did this question come into your mind? ;-)

Comment: Going to buy a loupe? ;-D

Comment: As hint for readers able to read German: [Was sind catcodes, lccodes und uccodes?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3281/was-sind-catcodes-lccodes-und-uccodes)

Comment: ;-) One upvote is mine, the other ones need new glasses like OP I will not name here …

Comment: *For future readers*: I made a package to allow you to write LaTeX code with unusual catcode/charcode easier/more readably https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638824/250119 (although the performance is to be improved)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your intuition is wrong. In TeX's syntax,

```
`\~
```

is a number, precisely the ASCII code of the character appearing after the backquote (it can also be a length one control sequence, meaning just the same, to accommodate cases like `%`). So the assignment

```
\lccode`\~=`\.
```

is just the same as

```
\lccode 126=46
```

so the lowercase counterpart of the tilde becomes the period, as far as `\lowercase` is concerned.

*If* you write

```
\lccode`\~=\lccode`\.
```

then you'd assign the tilde the lccode 0, but it's *very* different.

---

Some more words may be good for the beginner. One can think to `\lccode` as an array of length 256, with its index starting at 0. The command

```
\lccode <number1> = <number2>
```

stores `<number2>` in the slot numbered `<number1>`. When `\lowercase` does its job and finds a character with charcode *x*, it looks in slot *x* of the `\lccode` array; if the numbers stored there is 0, `\lowercase` does nothing; otherwise it finds a number *y* > 0 and replaces the charcode *x* with the charcode *y* (not changing the catcode).

As usual in TeX, the same primitive that performs the assignment can be used for retrieving the value in the slot. Thus `` \the\lccode`\A `` will print 97 (under normal settings) and

```
\count255=\lccode`A
```

would store 97 in the count register 255. One might even say

```
\count\lccode`A=42
```

in order to store 42 in count register 97. But this doesn't seem good usage of `\lccode`. `;-)`

There are several other arrays besides `\lccode` and `\uccode`: `\sfcode` (space factor codes), `\mathcode` (math codes), `\delcode` (delimiter code) and `\catcode` (category code).