# !Missing control sequence inserted. <inserted text> \inaccessible

Tags: spacing, environments

Tried to found solution by myself but didn't find nothing certain, I'm still not very good in LaTeX. I have code which works well.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand\s{\nobreak \hskip\fill \allowbreak \space \hskip-\fill \relax}

\begin{document}
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\obeyspaces\let =\s
Lorem:~\uline{ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\hfill}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

But after I try to move `\obeyspaces\let =\s` command to environment header

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand\s{\nobreak \hskip\fill \allowbreak \space \hskip-\fill \relax}

\newenvironment{under}
{\obeyspaces\let =\s}
{}

\begin{document}
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{under}
Lorem:~\uline{ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\hfill}
\end{under}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting an error

`! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.13 \begin{under}`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an active space in the instruction

```
\let =\s
```

which can be done with the `\lowercase` trick, see [The \lowercase trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156759). The problem is that in

```
\newenvironment{under}
  {\obeyspace\let =\s}
  {}
```

the space is not active which it is in the “expanded” code because there `\obeyspaces` is executed prior to `\let`. In the `\newenvironment`, `\obeyspaces` is only stored and doesn't act until the environment is called.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand\spaceinunder{\nobreak \hskip\fill \allowbreak \space \hskip-\fill \relax}

\begingroup\lccode`~=` \lowercase{\endgroup
  \newenvironment{under}
  {\obeyspaces\let~=\spaceinunder}
  {}
}

\begin{document}
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{under}
Lorem:~\uline{ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\hfill}
\end{under}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps better definition:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand\spaceinunder{%
  \nobreak\hspace{\fill}\allowbreak\space\hspace{-\fill}\relax
}

\begingroup\lccode`~=` \lowercase{\endgroup
  \newenvironment{under}[1]
  {%
   \begin{flushright}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}\raggedright
   \obeyspaces\let~=\spaceinunder
  }
  {\end{minipage}\end{flushright}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{under}{0.7\textwidth}
Lorem:~\uline{ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\hfill}
\end{under}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's works well as it is. But how can I do the same when I will write `Lorem:~\uline{\ftext \stext labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\hfill}` where `\newcommand\ftext{ipsum dolor sit amet,}` `\newcommand\stext{consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut}`