# expl3 replacement for \lowercase trick

Tags: expl3, best-practices

Given this example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:n { `\* }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \foo #1
  {
    \group_begin:
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \ 
    \char_set_lccode:nn { `\* } { `\  }
    \tex_lowercase:D { \cs_set:Npn * } { Y }
%    \tl_lower_case:n { \cs_set:Npn * } { Y }
    #1
    \group_end:
  }
\group_end:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\catcode`\ \active
\gdef {X}
\gdef\fooarg{   }
\endgroup

\fooarg

\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\fooarg}
\end{document}
```

Within the argument of `\foo` active space characters are re-mapped to a new meaning. To not bring an active space into scope for the whole definition of `\foo`, [the `\lowercase` trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156759/the-lowercase-trick) was used.

There are two issues with this code:

1. The relevant line of the trick uses a "do not use" function, namely `\tex_lowercase:D`. Is there a more idiomatic way for replacing that whole pattern using `expl3`-only functions?
2. According to the documentation of `\char_set_lccode:nn`, `\tl_lower_case:n` seem to be the "official" `\tex_lowercase:D` replacement function. But when used in the above code it produces an error

   ```
   ! Undefined control sequence.
   <argument> *
   ```

   not only for `*` but also for several other characters. Why does this happen?

Comment: The ``\char_set_catcode_active:N \`` line seems quite suspicious

Comment: Note that `\tl_lower_case:n` is explicitly documented as being about converting 'text' case: it's not intended for any weird catcode stuff.

Comment: Related (regarding special catcode in expl3): [spacing - How do I insert a tie (~, non-breaking space, tilde) under expl3 syntax? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152222/how-do-i-insert-a-tie-non-breaking-space-tilde-under-expl3-syntax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use the `\lowercase` trick (at the expense of defining an additional function) for locally setting the meaning of an active character, thanks to `\char_set_active_eq:nN`.

However, you should not define `\foo` with an argument, or the argument would be collected and tokenized *before* the space becomes active.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \foo
  {
    \group_begin:
    \cs_set:Npn \siracusa_test: { Y }
    \char_set_active_eq:nN { `\  } \siracusa_test:
    \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\  }
    \__siracusa_foo:n
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__siracusa_foo:n #1
  {
    #1
    \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\catcode`\ \active
\gdef {X}
\gdef\fooarg{   }
\endgroup

\fooarg

\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\fooarg}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that the reason we have `\char_set_active_eq:nN` using a second function is that the latter should be a well-defined and documented code-level construct.