# How to add a backslash in an expl3 message?

Tags: expl3, package-writing

In my package there are several messages like this:

```
\msg_new:nnn { my-module }
  { something-not-define }
  { "#1"~cannot~be~defined,~a~command~with~the~same~name~has~already~existed. }
```

where `#1` is the name of a command. I would like to add a backslash before it, but don't know how -- I've tried `\string` or `\protect`, but `\string\ #1` produce an extra space while `\string\#1` simply become `\#1` in the final message.

Comment: Crosslink: general trick(s) to inject tokens with unusual catcodes [spacing - How do I insert a tie (~, non-breaking space, tilde) under expl3 syntax? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152222/how-do-i-insert-a-tie-non-breaking-space-tilde-under-expl3-syntax?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Crosslink: [I ask for the rationale for the inconvenient syntax in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60773586#60773586)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use `\iow_char:N \\`:

```latex
\msg_new:nnn { my-module }
  { something-not-define }
  {
    "\iow_char:N \\#1"~cannot~be~defined,~a~command~
    with~the~same~name~has~already~exists.
  }
```

but you can also use `\c_backslash_str`:

```latex
\msg_new:nnn { my-module }
  { something-not-define }
  {
    "\c_backslash_str #1"~cannot~be~defined,~a~command~
    with~the~same~name~has~already~exists.
  }
```

`\c_backslash_str` is a string variable that contains a `\`<sub><sub>12</sub></sub>, while `\iow_char:N` turns the following `\⟨char⟩` into `⟨char⟩`, so it works for other characters like `\{`, `\}`, `#`, and `%`, that usually can't be easily written.